Resolving warning message NDSolve::icres
I am trying to use NDSolve for this system, but I suspect that it doesn't work
coeff = 500; 
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][RHO][R]/
    RHO[R] == -( R/(1 + R^2)) - Derivative[1][σ][R], 
   Derivative[1][σ][R] == -((
     coeff ((3.2 R^2)/(1 + R^2)^2 - R Derivative[1][ψ][R]))/R), 
   Derivative[1][ψ][R]/R +  Derivative[2][ψ][R] == 
    4 π RHO[R], 
   Derivative[1][ψ][10^-8] == 10^-8, ψ[10^-8] == 10^-8, 
   Derivative[1][σ][10^-8] == - 10^-8, 
   Derivative[1][RHO][10^-8] == 10^-8}, {σ[R], 
   RHO[R], ψ[R]}, {R, 10^-8, 4}];

Pot[R_] = ψ[R] /. sol[[1]][[3]];

Plot[{Sqrt[R Pot'[R]], Sqrt[ 3.2 R^2/(1 + R^2)^2]} , {R, 0.01, 4.}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"R", "V", "Vcirc en bleu Vdiff en orange"}]

My result is certainly false with the undocumented error icres:

NDSolve::icres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving explicit initial values to all dependent variables is recommended.

Does anybody know this error?

@ Domen thanks a lot  for editing !

Consider your boundary conditions:
bc = {Derivative[1][\[Psi]][10^-8] -> 10^-8, \[Psi][10^-8] -> 10^-8, 
   Derivative[1][\[Sigma]][10^-8] -> -10^-8, 
   Derivative[1][RHO][10^-8] -> 10^-8};

and now look at e.g. your second equation at R==10^-8:
Derivative[1][\[Sigma]][
    R] == -((coeff ((3.2 R^2)/(1 + R^2)^2 - 
          R Derivative[1][\[Psi]][R]))/R) /. R -> 10^-8 /. bc

False

Your boundary conditions are in contradiction to your equations.

@ Daniel Huber Ohh yes !   thank you very much. I was searching, unsuccessfully....
